# How are the rules in a network protocol defined?

Tags: network

New to network protocols here. Everywhere I read about network protocols it keeps claiming that they are simply just some rules and guidelines that allow computers to link to networks - but how is this actually defined? Are the way that these rules are defined uniform across different protocols with just the logic of the rule substituted?

Comment: Your question is far too broad to be answered here. The answer would take up several books.

Answer (score 2):

The protocols in use today are defined either by a standards body or they are created and defined by a particular manufacturer.

Most of the protocols you use in network communications have been defined by either the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF), or the Institute for Electrical an Electronic Engineers (IEEE).  These two standards bodies define the majority of the protocols you study.  Ethernet, WiFi, and the entire TCP/IP suite are defined by these two.

Other protocols are created by equipment manufacturers, and become standardized because they are in widespread use, and others manufacturers want to inter-operate with them.  Microsoft SMB, Cisco CDP, Netflow, and EIGRP are just a few examples.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=HAOVNYSnL7k - "BGP at 18: Lessons In Protocol Design."  Protocols can also be developed during lunch break using some napkins. ;-)